# display phplot graph inside a html div

Tags: php, graph, phplot

I'm using phplot library to display graphs. I've picked an example from their documentations and tried it with some data. It worked fine on simple php page.

here is the code

```
$column_names = array(
                 'Beef', 'Fish', 'Pork', 'Chicken', 'Butter',
                                                         'Cheese',
                                                               'Ice Cream');
//                   |       |       |       |       |       |       |
$data = array(
    array('1910',   48.5,   11.2,   38.2,   11.0,   18.4,    3.9,    1.9),
    array('1930',   33.7,   10.2,   41.1,   11.1,   17.6,    4.7,    9.7),
    array('1950',   44.6,   11.9,   43.0,   14.3,   10.9,    7.7,   17.4),
    array('1970',   79.6,   11.7,   48.1,   27.4,    5.4,   11.4,   17.8),
    array('1990',   63.9,   14.9,   46.4,   42.4,    4.0,   24.6,   15.8),
);
$plot = new PHPlot(800, 500);
$plot->SetImageBorderType('plain'); // Improves presentation in the manual
$plot->SetTitle("U.S. Annual Per-Capita Consumption\n"
              . "of Selected Meat and Dairy Products");
$plot->SetLegend($column_names);
#  Move the legend to the lower right of the plot area:
$plot->SetLegendPixels(700, 300);
$plot->SetDataValues($data);
$plot->SetDataType('text-data-yx');
$plot->SetPlotType('stackedbars');
$plot->SetXTitle('Pounds Consumed Per Capita');
#  Show data value labels:
$plot->SetXDataLabelPos('plotstack');
#  Rotate data value labels to 90 degrees:
$plot->SetXDataLabelAngle(90);
#  Format the data value labels with 1 decimal place:
$plot->SetXDataLabelType('data', 1);
#  Specify a whole number for the X tick interval:
$plot->SetXTickIncrement(20);
#  Disable the Y tick marks:
$plot->SetYTickPos('none');
$plot->DrawGraph();
```

But when i tried applying some html to display it at a fix position, i failed.
to display it html i wrote following code after writing above code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHPlot Example - Inline Image</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>PHPlot Example - Inline Image</h1>
<div class="graph">
<img src="<?php echo $plot->EncodeImage();?>" alt="Plot Image">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I got output like that [image]

please guide me that where i'm doing wrong. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by temporarily saving graph images and then used that temporary image to display inside image tag oh html.
here is the code

```
$plot->SetIsInline(True);
$plot->SetOutputFile("test.png");
```

image is saved as test.png. now display it like that

```
<div class="graph">
<img src="test.png" alt="Plot Image">
</div>
```